# OpenTK - Top Left Origin and pixel co-ordinates

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to learn how to use OpenGL in a 2D application by using OpenTK and have read that using the inbuilt calls glMatrixMode are not modern. I want to use top left origin and pixel co-ordinates in my shader inputs and assumed I could define a matrix to do these translations.

I am trying to do this using my own matrix using the OpenTK matrix clases. However I think I have made a mistake in setting up the projection matrix and want to verify what I should be doing:-

```
TranslationMatrix = Matrix4.Identity * Matrix4.CreateScale(1, -1, 1);
TranslationMatrix = TranslationMatrix * Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, bounds.Width, 0, bounds.Height, -1, 1);
var TranslatedPoint = TranslationMatrix * new Vector4(new Vector3(1024, 768, 0), 1); // bounds = {0, 0, 1024, 768 }
```

This results in `x.Xyz == { 2, -2, 0 }`. I thought that the x and y co-ordinates used in gl_position in the vertex shader should range from -1 to 1.

I guess I've got a major misunderstanding somewhere, what should I be looking at?

Comment: Which value does the w component have? The assumption of [-1, 1] on each axis is only true after homogenization (division by w).

Comment: After the multiplication w is -1791. The position vector is initialized with w as 1 before the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTK stores the matrices in transposed form. This means you have to write everything in reversed order.

```
var TranslationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, bounds.Width, 0, bounds.Height, -1, 1);
TranslationMatrix = TranslationMatrix * Matrix4.CreateScale(1, -1, 1);
var TranslatedPoint = new Vector4(1024, 768, 0, 1) * TranslationMatrix;
```

The result should now be `[1, -1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: Thankyou ever-so much - my white square on top of my purple square draws beautifully.